# Introducir un listview en un ScrollView

Tags: android, listview

Buenas intento introducir una ListView dinámica dentro de una vista tipo ScrollView, tengo un problemas que ya otros usuarios en internet han tenido y han solucionado, pero yo no soy capaz.
El problema es que mi ListView tiene anulado su Scroll y por lo tanto la vista si se mueve pero el ListView no.
Pongo el código, si es necesario más código para resolver la duda decidme.
Gracias de antemano

```
public class PantallaPrincipalDelFestival extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

private ViewPager view1;
private ScrollView paginainformacion;
private LinearLayout paginaartistas;
private LinearLayout paginanoticias;

private RatingBar ratingratingBar;
private Button btnValorar;

private Festival festival;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
festival = (Festival) getIntent().getExtras().get("festival");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                       .setAction("Action", null).show();
       }
 });

       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
               this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
       drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
       toggle.syncState();

       NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
       navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


       try{
           //implementacion slider
           view1=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view);
           view1.setAdapter(new AdminPageAdapter());
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }






}

class AdminPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position)
    {
        View paginaactual = null;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                if (paginainformacion == null)
                {
                    try{

                        paginainformacion = (ScrollView) LayoutInflater.from(PantallaPrincipalDelFestival.this).inflate(R.layout.paginainformacion, null);

                        //scrooll de pagina
                        paginainformacion.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                findViewById (R.id.listaCabezas) .getParent (). requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (false);
                                return false;
                            }
                        });





                        ImageView imagenPrincipal = (ImageView)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.imagenPrincipal);
                        ImageView imagenLogo = (ImageView)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.imagenLogo);
                        TextView ciudad = (TextView)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.labelLugar);
                        TextView fecha = (TextView)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.labelFecha);
                        TextView descripcion = (TextView)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.labelDescripcion);
                        ImageButton btnFacebook = (ImageButton)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.btnFacebook);
                        Button btnWeb = (Button)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.btnWeb);
                        ImageButton btnInstagram = (ImageButton)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.btnInstagram);
                        ImageButton btnTwitter = (ImageButton)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.btnTwitter);
                        ListView listaCabezasCartel = (ListView)paginainformacion.findViewById(R.id.listaCabezas);

                        //scroll de vista
                        listaCabezasCartel.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                v.getParent ().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (true);
                                return false;
                            }
                        });



                        Date fechaFestivalInicio = festival.getFechaInicio();
                        Date fechaFestivalFin = festival.getFechaFin();
                        String fechaPantalla = "";
                        //procesamos la fecha
                        SimpleDateFormat formatoAnyo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
                        SimpleDateFormat formatoMes = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
                        SimpleDateFormat formatoDía = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
                        String anyo = formatoAnyo.format(fechaFestivalInicio);
                        String mes = formatoMes.format(fechaFestivalInicio);
                        mes = procesarMes(mes);
                        String diaInicio = formatoDía.format(fechaFestivalInicio);
                        String diaFin = formatoDía.format(fechaFestivalFin);

                        fechaPantalla = diaInicio+" - "+diaFin+" de "+mes+" del "+anyo;



                        fecha.setText(fechaPantalla);
                        ciudad.setText(festival.getLocalidad());
                        descripcion.setText(festival.getDescripcion());
                        imagenLogo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(festival.getImagenLogo(),0,festival.getImagenLogo().length));
                        imagenPrincipal.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(festival.getImagenPral(),0,festival.getImagenPral().length));
                        btnWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Uri uri = Uri.parse(festival.getSitioWeb());
                                Intent webFestival = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
                                startActivity(webFestival);
                            }
                        });

                        btnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                //debemos recoger otro campo con el nombre de la pagina web en facebook
                                String paginaFacebook = "https://www.facebook.com/"+festival.getNombrePerfilFacebook()+"/";
                                String facebookID = "fb://page/"+festival.getFacebook();

                                //controla si tienes instalada la aplicación de facebook o la lanza por el navegador
                                try{
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(facebookID)));
                                }catch (Exception e){

                                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(paginaFacebook)));
                                }

                            }
                        });

                        btnInstagram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String scheme = "http://instagram.com/_u/"+festival.getInstagram();
                                String path = "https://instagram.com/"+festival.getInstagram();
                                Intent paginaInstagram = null;
                                try {
                                    paginaInstagram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(scheme));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    paginaInstagram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(path));
                                }finally {
                                    startActivity(paginaInstagram);

                                }
                            }
                        });

                        btnTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent paginaTwitter = null;
                                try{
                                    paginaTwitter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name="+festival.getInstagram()));
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    paginaTwitter = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/"+festival.getNombrePerfilTwitter()));
                                }finally {
                                    startActivity(paginaTwitter);
                                }
                            }
                        });




                        ArrayList<Artista> artistasCabezasCartel = obtenerCabezasCartel(festival.getListaArtistas());

                        AdaptadorArtistaBasico adaptadorCabezasCartel = new AdaptadorArtistaBasico(getApplicationContext(),artistasCabezasCartel,listaCabezasCartel,this);
                        listaCabezasCartel.setAdapter(adaptadorCabezasCartel);

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
                paginaactual = paginainformacion;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (paginaartistas == null)
                {
                    paginaartistas = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(PantallaPrincipalDelFestival.this).inflate(R.layout.paginaartistas, null);

                    ListView listaArtistasView = (ListView)paginaartistas.findViewById(R.id.listaArtistasGeneral);

                    AdaptadorArtistaBasico adaptadorArtistasBasico = new AdaptadorArtistaBasico(getApplicationContext(),festival.getListaArtistas(),listaArtistasView,this);
                    listaArtistasView.setAdapter(adaptadorArtistasBasico);

                }
                paginaactual = paginaartistas;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (paginanoticias == null)
                {
                    paginanoticias = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(PantallaPrincipalDelFestival.this).inflate(R.layout.paginanoticias, null);
                }
                paginaactual = paginanoticias;
                break;
        }
        ViewPager vp=(ViewPager) collection;
        vp.addView(paginaactual, 0);
        return paginaactual;
    }





    private String procesarMes(String mes) {
        String mesCadena = "";
        switch (mes){
            case "01":
                mesCadena = "Enero";
            break;
            case "02":
                mesCadena = "Febrero";
                break;
            case "03":
                mesCadena = "Marzo";
                break;
            case "04":
                mesCadena = "Abril";
                break;
            case "05":
                mesCadena = "Mayo";
                break;
            case "06":
                mesCadena = "Junio";
                break;
            case "07":
                mesCadena = "Julio";
                break;
            case "08":
                mesCadena = "Agosto";
                break;
            case "09":
                mesCadena = "Septiembre";
                break;
            case "10":
                mesCadena = "Octubre";
                break;
            case "11":
                mesCadena = "Noviembre";
                break;
            case "12":
                mesCadena = "Diciembre";
                break;











        }

        return mesCadena;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == object;
    }


    public void detalleArtista(Artista artista){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha pulsado al artista "+artista.getNombreArtista(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view)
    {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

}
```

Perdon por el código tan largo, aún falta por refactorizar, puesto que estamos probando algunas cosas en la aplicación de Android.

Añado por aqui la vista de ScrollView que contiene el ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:fillViewport="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutInfoPral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagenPrincipal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="186dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/pruebaimagenfondo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagenLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.582"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logoprueba" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelLugar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="Barcelona"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imagenLogo"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelFecha"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="27 Mayo - 2 Julio 2019"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imagenLogo"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutLinks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutInfoPral"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWeb"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/spinner_dropdown_background"
            android:text="Visitar WEB"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnInstagram"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.134"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logoinstagram" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTwitter"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logotwitter" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="252dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="252dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.208"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logofacebook" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutCabezas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutInfoPral"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCabezas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Cabezas de Cartel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listaCabezas"
            android:layout_width="354dp"
            android:layout_height="370dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Agustin, te recomiendo que des una vuelta por el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona StackOverflow y así de paso ganas tu primera medalla. Es importante que leas: [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ya que la pregunta no queda del todos clara. ¿Que has probado? ¿Es necesario todo ese código para encontrar/resolver el problema?

Comment: Muestra por favor las vistas que estas usando.

Comment: Buenas soy nuevo por aquí, y aún no se como funciona muy bien esto, para agregar nuevo código debo editar el anterior comentario o se puede añadir código en las respuestas a comentarios, gracias.

Comment: Hola!! te pasaron unos links para que revises y sepas como funcionamos, los leiste??? Para editar tu publicación, hay un link debajo de ella que dice [edit]. Presiona sobre el y hace todos los cambios necesarios. Hay una seccion de pregunta (alli donde la hiciste) y una seccion de respuestas (abajo, donde van solo respuestas). Y esta es la sección de comentarios, donde te pedimos mas información o te damos mas información como esta ;)

Comment: Ya añadí el código de la vista que contiene el scroll y el listview

Comment: Hola Agustin, hacer un listview dentro de un scroll no esta bueno, te recomiendo que quites el scroll y dejes el listview. Para que las demas vistas se muevan junto con el scroll del listview deberias usar layout_behavior y app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"

Comment: La idea de hacerlo así, es porque la pagina de informacion tiene varios componentes y como es dinámica y unas veces es mayor y otras menor, varía su tamaño y para poder mostrarlos todos y además meter en ella una lista con varios cantantes lo diseñe asi, he visto en varios sitios una solucion de declarar un evento en el scroll y en la listview pero no consigo que me funcione